# Why can covariance be written both of these ways?

Tags: probability

I read from a text book that covariance is $E((X - EX)(Y - EY))$. The book then states that this expression is equivalent to $E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$. Where did the latter expression come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(X-EX)(Y-EY)=XY-(EY)X-(EX)Y+(EX)(EY)$, and expectation is linear, so

$$\begin{align*}
E\big((X-EX)(Y-EY)\big)&=E(XY)-(EY)EX-(EX)EY+(EX)(EY)\\
&=E(XY)-(EX)(EY)\;.
\end{align*}$$

If you get lost in all the expectations, let $\alpha=E(X)$ and $\beta=E(Y)$; then

$$(X-\alpha)(Y-\beta)=XY-\beta X-\alpha Y+\alpha\beta\;,$$ and

$$\begin{align*}
E\big((X-\alpha)(Y-\beta)\big)&=E(XY)-\beta E(X)-\alpha E(Y)+\alpha\beta\\
&=E(XY)-\beta\alpha-\alpha\beta+\alpha\beta\\
&=E(XY)-\alpha\beta\\
&=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense overall. I also expanded out the factors, but I'm wondering why we can say that $E(E(Y)X) = EYEX$?

Comment: @David: Because $E(Y)$ is a constant, the one that I called $\beta$, and $E$ is linear: $E(\beta X)=\beta E(X)$, just as with any linear function.

Comment: Ah thank you! That makes sense!

Comment: @David: You’re welcome.